# Choosing between a Filter and a Service

Tags: angularjs

I have function that collates an array of objects received from a REST service into groups while also applying ordering that is set out by user preference only available on the client.

Currently this collation is handled in the Service that calls the REST service but I see a need to separate this functionality from the actual $HTTP call because the user can switch between different collating instructions without reissuing the $HTTP call.

Since this isn't a simple reordering is it appropriate to create this collation process as a another Service or as a Filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters are UI constructs where Services are not.  If you find yourself making `$http` calls, then they should be in a Service (or Factory).  If you find yourself wanting to create a filter that is also responsible for collecting data, I'd do this:

1. Create a service which is responsible for fetching the data
2. Inject the service into your controller and expose the service data via the controller
3. Bind the data from the controller to the filter parameter

Doing this will preserve proper separation of concerns.

Comment: I am revealing my own confusion here.  The data that I retrieve from the service remains bound (in the $rootScope and in localStorage) but the collated data is only held in the view.  I gues you are right that a filter is the correct solution for the collation.